# Websocket giving various numbers depending on OS

Tags: android, ios, xcode, tcp, websocket

I'm doing a little test where I send out a short string(4-8 bytes) to a client every 0.5 seconds from a Node.js server using [ws](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws). The client is either using iOS/Android or a web browser. The client does not send anything back to the server, except for TCP-ACKS I suppose. The weird thing is, when I'm debugging the app in iOS using XCode network report, I can only see that the client sends out some bytes(approx 500) when the connections establishes, probably during the HTTP handshake. The remaining time ZERO data is going out from the device, there is only data coming in. The same results is achieved when receiving data in Chrome and tracking the data using Nettop.

The thing that makes so confused is that on the Android, almost the same amount of data that goes in to the device goes out when inspecting the network usage with Android profiler/Battery Historian/TrafficStats. I have tried using different libraries for the Websocket implementation and using different Android devices.

I have a hard time believing the ACKS sent out by the android is as big as the message received, even though it's just a small string of four characters.

So my questions are:

1. Could the case be that Nettop/XCode network report is simply ignoring all the ACKS, so in reality as much data is sent out in Chrome/iOS as in Android?
2. Is there something 'Wrong' with the libraries used in Android or could it be something with its operating system?
3. Could an ACK be as big as a simple TCP-package with 4 characters in it?

The result below when using Websocket

The data received/transmitted when using Android Battery Historian
[image]

The data received/transmitted on iOS using Network Report
[image]

Comment: what is your nodejs code?

Comment: This just sounds like a difference in your measuring tools.  XCode is probably measuring only at the app layer and not counting TCP housekeeping stuff, while the Android tool is probably counting all bytes sent, regardless of what layer.  The initial connection request will include any cookies that client has saved that are associated with that domain so that could vary significantly from one client to another depending upon prior browsing history to that domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could an ACK be as big as a simple TCP-package with 4 characters in it?

An ACK consists of the IP and the TCP header and no payload. With IPv4 this means at least 20 bytes IP header and 20 bytes TCP header, i.e. 40 bytes. A packet with 4 bytes payload is only larger by 4 bytes, i.e. 44 bytes or just 10%.

The network report in Android shows 68350 in vs. 61370 in bytes, which is a difference of 11%. This matches the expected difference.

I'm not familiar with what iOS measure here, but it probably either measures only the application payload (i.e. the 4 bytes) or simply ignores packets with no payload, i.e. the ACK's.